# Restangular 2 set default headers

Tags: angular, restangular

I try set default headers after login to my app. In my login component I import `restangular`

```
import { RestangularModule, Restangular } from 'ng2-restangular';
```

Set constructor

```
  constructor(private loginService : LoginService, private uiRouter:UIRouter, private restangular: Restangular) { }
```

And in my login method if login and password match to user I would like set token in header. I write this like here :

```
  login(){
  this.loginService.getAuthenticate(this.user.name, this.user.password)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'x-access-token':data.token});
        this.uiRouter.stateService.go('dashboard');
    })
 }
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`private restangular: Restangular` this object has no setDefaultHeaders function, you need to use withConfig

```
restangular.withConfig((RestangularConfigurer) => {
      RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({'x-access-token':data.token});
});
```